# Maria DB storage capacity and pricing

Tags: storage, mariadb, price, swisscomdev, capacity-planning

Currently starting plan for Maria DB is only 1 GB. I would rather expect to have next plans: S - 5 GB, M - 35 GB and L - 100 GB. Is there any plan to extend Maria DB storage plans?

We are expecting to release one App hosted in Swisscom Cloud that could produce 500 MB under Maria DB each month. With current Maria DB plans we would rapidly go out of storage.

Comment: You are referring to disk space?

Comment: To save on disk space, it would be wise to use the smallest practical datatypes.  For example, there are 5 sizes of integers, not just the 4-byte `INT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swisscom will change price model for MariaDB as a Service and renew/optimise the Galera setup. This will happen soon. Please subscribe to the [newsletter](http://swisscom.us12.list-manage.com/subscribe?u=6d3304d634e2c78b4e37ebc19&id=dda6a7f0cc) for dates and announcments. The new MariaDB service will be billed by disk usage. The price model will be similar to S3 (dynstrg).

Please contact [Swisscom Support](http://developer.swisscom.com/support) product management for capacity planning. I guess the current setup won't be suitable for your growth needs.